# Can a virus be transferred from a device to a mobile hotspot/router, then from the hotspot/router to other devices?

Tags: router, internet, virus, desktop-computer, mobile-hotspot

If a device (e.g. a smartphone, tablet, or laptop) is infected with a virus, can this virus be spread from the device to the router/hotspot the device is connected to, then from the router/hotspot to other device that connect to the router/hotspot?

Yes, i understand that for such spread to happen, the virus must be specially designed to infect the type of operating systems used in routers and mobile hotspots. But, do such viruses exist, or am i worrying for no good reason? I have a laptop i'm pretty sure has an advanced, well-engineered BIOS/UEFI virus. I'm afraid that if i connect this laptop to the mobile hotspot my other devices use, the other devices may get infected, too.

So, is such virus transmission possible, resulting in decryption of data that needs to be encrypted, stolen data, corruption of transferred data, missing packets, etc...?

Comment: It's not duplicate

Comment: Added more duplicates. Per the last duplicate the answer is "Maybe".

Comment: @onaquest64 - Yeah, it absolutely is a duplicate. If the infected device is air gapped you can remove the infection easily.

Comment: If you absolutely believe you have some advanced UEFI virus then that machine is already lost. Any firmware update you do could be detected, blocked, subverted or otherwise patched to still include the malicious payload. At that point [this](https://youtu.be/ylW6qLo5CyY?si=ebJlHGNHESi_DJSP&t=48) is your only option because the only other thing you can do is to desolder every possible chip on the motherboard and replace them from a known-good source.